# Pure Directed Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, functional-programming, haskell

How can a directed graph be efficiently represented in a purely functional language like Haskell? Could someone suggest relevant materials on this topic? (functional pearls perhaps?) Thanks.

Comment: This was asked and nicely answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38881393/394327

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasonable approaches, but one is an adjacency list representation.  You can use any convenient data structure for the adjacency list; I anticipate that a dictionary (ordered map) will be useful.